# What is the D7 equivalent of CCK "content_instance_tablename" in db_query?

Tags: entities

I am porting a D6 module to D7 which deals with controlling field access of CCK fields. I can now successfully enable my port without any errors but receive a fatal error when trying to create new content.

The issue is the the "content_table_instance" in db_query which as far as I understand no longer exists in D7 due to the CCK --> Fields move. I am having a lot of trouble finding exactly what the alternative of "content_table_instance" is in D7. Any suggestions?

Here is the section of the code:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nfi.field_name, nfi.label
  FROM {" . content_instance_tablename() . "} nfi
    INNER JOIN {" . content_field_tablename() . "} nf ON nfi.field_name = nf.field_name
  WHERE nfi.type_name = '%s' AND nf.active = 1 AND nf.locked = 0", $type_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions in your code ([`content_field_tablename()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21cck%21content.module/function/content_field_tablename/6) and [`content_instance_tablename()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21cck%21content.module/function/content_instance_tablename/6)) just return a string based on the version number of the CCK module.

The Drupal 7 equivalents would be the `field_config` and `field_config_instance` tables respectively, as defined in [`field_schema`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.install/function/field_schema/7).

Remember fields can be attached to any entity in Drupal 7 (not just nodes) so you'll need to change your code accordingly.

If you're using this query to get information about the field metadata you might want to use one of the [Field Info API functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/group/field_info/7) instead, e.g.

```
$all_field_instance_data = field_info_instances();
```

or

```
$single_field_instance_data = field_info_instance('node', 'field_some_field', 'article');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really helpful. I am starting to wonder whether porting this module is actually beyond me. Unfortunately there is no other alternative available in any current D7 module and I really need this functionality. I'm not a programmer but since there is no other option at this point I've decided to bite the bullet and give this a try. There are over 20 people subscribed for the D7 version of this module but little progress has yet been made by anyone. Thanks again

Comment: Are you porting a module that deals with permissions for CCK fields? If so, there's already one out there for the D7 field system: [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions/)

Comment: Thanks again. Yes I do know about Field Permissions, unfortunately though it does not integrate with User Relationships module which is the functionality I need: to be able to hide/show user fields based a user's relationship to another or lack there of. I have also tried doing this functionality via Rules module but couldn't achieve it to this level. This is why I am trying to port CCK Private Fields, but if there are better options out there I am all ears.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't know of any I'm afraid

Comment: That's ok, thank you anyway. Hopefully, if I manage to get this together I can make it available for everyone else also :)